# Area between curve and line. Find the sum of all possible $a$ of the line

Tags: geometry

Let $R$ be the region enclosed by the curve $y=3x^{3}+2x$, the line $x=a$, and the line $y=0$. If the area of $R$ is 1, find the sum of all possible $a$.

Is there any clue to find the $a$ and how's the integral would be?

Comment: Try integrate your function from 0 to a and then set the result = 1. From which, find a.

Comment: $x=0,y=0$ is the only $x$-intersect so just integrate the curve over $x=0$ to $x=a$.

Comment: Depends on whether negative $a$ is allowed, and if so whether it is signed area or geometric area, If geometric area then a sketch, with no computation, shows the sum is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of $y=3x^{3}+2x$ is essentially cubic.  In particular, to the left of $x=0$, the curve is below the $x$-axis, and to the right of $x=0$, it is above.  Thus, we have two cases to consider: $$\int_{a}^{0}\int_{3x^{3}+2x}^{0}1dydx$$ and $$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{3x^{3}+2x}1dydx$$ the first being when $a<0$ and the second being when $a>0$.  In each case, setting the double integral equal to $1$ and performing the iterated integral leads to the quartic equation $$0=\frac{3}{4}a^{4}+a^{2}-1$$ which yields $$a^{2}=-2,\frac{2}{3}$$ Clearly, the only real solutions are $a=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$, whose sum is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you [plotted the curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E3%2B2x%3D0)?  It goes through $(0,0)$.  If $a$ is positive, you need to integrate the curve and find what upper limit gives an area of $1$.  For $x \lt 0$ the curve is negative, which will lead to a negative area if you integrate from $a$ to $0$.  If you are supposed to view the area as positive, you need to find the negative $a$ that leads to an area of $1$.